# Using Xsl:value-of is converting & in url into &amp;

Tags: xslt

I have a xml something likethis

```
<root>
<testxml>
<details  name="test" url="http://www.test.com/test.aspx?val=100&val2=200" />
</testxml>
<root>
```

When i transform this xml using xslt to another xml

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"  />

<xsl:template match="root/testxml/details">
    <convert>
        <xsl:attribute name="url">
            <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </convert>
```

I get the result output as this

```
<convert url="http://www.test.com/test.aspx?val=100&amp;val2=200">
```

instead of

```
<convert url="http://www.test.com/test.aspx?val=100&val2=200">
```

**issue here is: & in url is getting changed to & amp;** how can i avoid this ,i want & in url as &.(not & amp;)

i tried `<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@url"  />` 
also but of not use.

could anyone please help me in this..

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a detailed explanation why the reported behavior is actually *not* a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get the result output as this
>
> instead of
>
> issue here is: & in url is getting
>   changed to & amp;

**There is no issue and the URL is not changed at all**:

To verify this use a transformation like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<convert url="http://www.test.com/test.aspx?val=100&amp;val2=200"/>
```

**The result is**:

```
http://www.test.com/test.aspx?val=100&val2=200
```

So, the URL hasn't been changed in any way and there is still only a single `&` character in it.

What you observe is the mandatory escaping of some special characters (typically `<` and `&`) in XML, as dictated by the XML Spec.

**The escaping of some special characters never alters the content of the string that is escaped** -- only how it looks like when it is a part of an XML document.

> how can i avoid this ,i want & in url
>   as &.(not & amp;)

**You cannot, and as shown above, there is nothing to avoid.**

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge , now i got a clear idea.

Answer (score 1):

& has to be escaped as &amp; in a URL in an XML document. You can't have an unescaped ampersand like that.

Answer (score 1):

Dimitre is quite correct - an ampersand in XML must always be escaped, and it's not clear why you're trying so hard to prevent it.

I'm puzzled though - you say you're generating XML, but you use the HTML output method, but you are generating a `<convert>` element which isn't defined in HTML. So I fear you are a little confused by something.

Comment: You are right , i was using html as output.it should be xml. I made a url in xml (ampersand escaped),after transformation im getting proper url.